# Lightweight alternative to isotope.js

Tags: animation, jquery-isotope

I'm using [isotope.js](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) purely because of its animations for adding/removing elements.

I love the effect of items animating to fill the position of removed elements simultaneously as the removed elements fade out.

The thing is, my grid elements are all of a fixed and equal size, and I don't need any of the filtering stuff. I find isotope to be a little clunky, maybe because of the breadth of its functionality.

So I'm looking for an alternative which is:

- lightweight
- slick
- robust and production ready
- able to gracefully degrade

Comment: Hmmm, what your describing, adding/removing elements, is the filtering "stuff" of isotope, so I'm not sure how you don't need it.

Comment: Please Check out my Code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241431/web-animation-library-for-code-editor-animation/72484383#72484383

Answer (score 35):

**Original answer**

If someone is still looking you might also want to take a look into a similar jQuery plugin I've written, **Filterizr**. Filterizr is:

- Allows for **filtering**, **sorting**, **shuffling** and **searching**
- Highly customizable (allows users to write their own CSS effects for the transitions when filtering in and out)
- Uses **CSS3 transitions and transform-translate**.
- Lightweight, **~20kb**
- Optimized for **mobile performance**
- **Responsive** (with your media queries)
- Open source and **MIT** licensed

Download links, tutorials and docs on the
 [Filterizr Website](http://yiotis.net/filterizr)

---

**Update 06/2019:**

Filterizr has come a long way since then.

It is now written in TypeScript JavaScript and can be used without jQuery as a vanilla JavaScript library.

It still allows usage as a jQuery plugin though, you can still consult the Filterizr website as it's up-to-date.

Comment: Its really nice and lightweight .

Comment: Great job! I'll try it since I have the same requirements that guided your development.

Comment: Awesome plugin can i use it with masonry ?

Comment: Please Check out my Code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241431/web-animation-library-for-code-editor-animation/72484383#72484383

Answer (score 11):

In case someone is still looking check out 
[Shuffle.js](http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/). It is responsive alongwith MIT license.

Comment: Please Check out my Code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241431/web-animation-library-for-code-editor-animation/72484383#72484383

Answer (score 10):

I also searching that have extensive filter with animation:

[Muuri - Open Source MIT](https://haltu.github.io/muuri/) (Seem Fast and Good)

[MixitUp - High Quality Commercial Library](https://www.kunkalabs.com/mixitup/) (Extreme Polished)

Other open source either do not have both feature, or optional extensible, Good if you need fast animation only like Macy.js, gridfolio, Tympanus CSS (+ equal included, - equal excluded):

- [Macy.js: Animation +, Filtering -](http://macyjs.com/) (Very lack of documentation of css transition)
- [gridfolio: Animation+, Filtering -](https://github.com/christinecha/gridfolio/#special-features)
- [Mansory: Animation +, Filtering -](https://masonry.desandro.com/) - (but maybe with https://github.com/dynamick/multiple-filter-masonry)
- [Filtrify: Animation - , Filtering +](http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/)
- [Tympanus CSS Tutorial: Animation +, Filtering -](https://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/)
- [Boardz.css: Animation -, Filtering -](https://github.com/karakanb/boardz) (Notable for mention as HQ CSS only Library)
- [jquery Woodmark: Animation +, Filtering -](https://github.com/germanysbestkeptsecret/Wookmark-jQuery) (Polished Demo)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting MixItUp!

Comment: Please Check out my Code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241431/web-animation-library-for-code-editor-animation/72484383#72484383

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you're looking for [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

In general Isotope is pretty slick for most cases, all depending on the amount of content you throw at it of course.

The reason behind the clunkyness might be jQuery itself. While jQuery is an amazing selector, it's animation and speed of manipulation is lacking a bit because of the sheer amount of functionality included in the lib.

Comment: Isotope is using Mansonry as backend. It seems to be from the same author.

Comment: @Tombart Yes. But Masonry is the lightweight alternative to using the complete Isotope package. As long as you don't need filtering and animations, Masonry alone will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

im using jquery Quicksand which is pretty neat and straight forward http://razorjack.net/quicksand/

Answer (score -3):

I have also found some **alternative of isotope masonry gallery**

https://www.wix.com/app-market/wix-pro-gallery

https://github.com/wix/pro-gallery

```
            ---------------OR---------------
```

Image Photo Gallery Final Tiles Grid  (**Wordpress plugin**)

Meow Gallery (+ Gallery Block) (**Wordpress plugin**)

Comment: i dont see any mention of react or wix.