# Web animation library for code editor animation

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations

Both stripe.com and vercel.com have a really cool code editor animation on their landing page, which when I inspect it, is compiled to HTML.

What javascript libraries are used to make these types of native web animations? Any npm packages to consider?

Comment: does anybody found this?

Comment: For https://lowdefy.com I ended up using `react-syntax-highlighter` and writing a custom animation for the text string passed to it. Which produced a reasonably nice type effect. Although it could be better.

Comment: hmm.. nice. I also found an alternate way and used https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/ script. you can see over here https://www.payok.app/en

Comment: Check out my code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241431/web-animation-library-for-code-editor-animation/72484383#72484383

Answer (score 1):

Isotope is a good library for JS animation.
I thought will it be that difficult to write something in the likes of the Isotope JS library?
Here I present Isometric.
It is a small class that uses JQuery and Bootstrap 5.x.x. for CSS.
Remember to include this below IsoMetric class into the head or put it into a separate .js, and then include it in the head of the HTML file

```
class IsoMetric {
// 1: ZoomOutMoveInAndZoomIn , 2: FadeOffAppearAndFadeIn, 3: ImplodeExplode, 4: Rotation
constructor(item_container, item_identifier, animationOption) {
    this.animationOption = animationOption ? animationOption : 1;
    this.jItemsContainer = $(item_container);
    this.leftCont = this.jItemsContainer.position().left;
    this.topCont = this.jItemsContainer.position().top;
    this.wdCont = parseFloat(this.jItemsContainer.width());
    this.htCont = parseFloat(this.jItemsContainer.height());
    this.eleJArray = $(item_identifier);
    this.eleArray = this.eleJArray.toArray();
    this.allPositions = [];
    let that = this;
    $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, ele) {
        let $ele = $(ele);
        let pos = $ele.position();
        let onePos = { "x": pos.left + "px", "y": pos.top + "px", "w": $ele.width(), "h": $ele.height() };
        that.allPositions.push(onePos);
        $ele.attr(onePos);
        let par = $ele;
        //while (true) { //I restore width of all parents leading up to the container.
        //    par = $(par).parent();
        //    if (par[0] === that.jItemsContainer[0]) break;
        //    $(par).css({ "width": $(par).width(), "height": $(par).height() });
        //}
    });
    $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, ele) {
        let $ele = $(ele);
        $ele.css({ "position": "absolute", "left": $ele.attr("x"), "top": $ele.attr("y") });
    });
    this.jItemsContainer.css({ "width": this.wdCont + "px", "height": this.htCont + "px" });
}
TheClick(e, selector) {
    $(e.target).siblings().removeClass("filter-active");
    $(e.target).addClass("filter-active");
    switch (this.animationOption) {
        case 1:
            this.ZoomOutMoveInAndZoomIn(e, selector);
            break;
        case 2:
            this.FadeOffAppearAndFadeIn(e, selector);
            break;
        case 3:
            this.ImplodeExplode(e, selector);
            break;
        case 4:
            this.Rotation(e, selector);
            break;
    }
}
SetAnimation(option) {
    this.animationOption = option;
}
ZoomOutMoveInAndZoomIn(e, selector) {
    let boneEle = $(selector);
    let that = this;
    $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, bEle) {
        $(bEle).animate({
            "width": 0,
            "height": 0,
            "left": parseFloat($(bEle).position().left) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("w") / 2),
            "top": parseFloat($(bEle).position().top) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("h") / 2),
            //"opacity": 0,
        }, 800, function () {
            //$(bEle).css({ "opacity": 0 });
            //$(bEle).css({ "display": "none" });
        });
    });
    $.each(boneEle, function (index, bEle) {
        //$(bEle).css({ "display": "block" });
        $(bEle).animate({
            "left": that.allPositions[index].x,
            "top": that.allPositions[index].y,
            "width": $(bEle).attr("w"),
            "height": $(bEle).attr("h"),
            //"opacity": 1
        }, 200);
    });
}
FadeOffAppearAndFadeIn(e, selector) {
    let boneEle = $(selector);
    let that = this;
    $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, bEle) {
        $(bEle).animate({"opacity": 0,}, 1000, function () {
            $(bEle).css({ "width": 0, "height": 0 });
        });
    });
    $(":animated").promise().done(function () {
        //code here
        $.each(boneEle, function (index, bEle) {
            $(bEle).css({
                "left": that.allPositions[index].x,
                "top": that.allPositions[index].y,
                "width": that.allPositions[index].w,
                "height": that.allPositions[index].h
            });
            $(bEle).animate({
                "opacity": 1
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
}
ImplodeExplode(e, selector) {
    let boneEle = $(selector);
    let that = this;
    let Cx = that.leftCont + (that.wdCont / 2); let Cy = that.topCont + (that.htCont / 2);
    $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, bEle) {
        $(bEle).animate({
            "left": Cx , //that.allPositions[index].x,
            "top": Cy , //that.allPositions[index].y,
            "width": 0,
            "height": 0,
        }, 100);
    });
    $(":animated").promise().done(function () {
        //code here
        $.each(boneEle, function (index, bEle) {
            $(bEle).animate({
                "left": that.allPositions[index].x,
                "top": that.allPositions[index].y,
                "width": $(bEle).attr("w"),
                "height": $(bEle).attr("h"),
                "opacity": 1
            }, 800);
        });
    });
}
Rotation(e, selector) {
    let boneEle = $(selector);
    let that = this;
    $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, bEle) {
        $({
            deg: 0, w: $(bEle).width(), h: $(bEle).height(),
            l: parseFloat($(bEle).position().left),
            t: parseFloat($(bEle).position().top),
            o: 1
        }).animate({
            deg: 360, w: 0, h: 0,
            l: parseFloat($(bEle).position().left) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("w") / 2),
            t: parseFloat($(bEle).position().top) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("h") / 2),
            o: 0
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            index: index,
            step: function () {
                // in the step-callback (that is fired each step of the animation),
                // you can use the `now` paramter which contains the current
                // animation-position (`0` up to `angle`)
                //let xx = parseFloat($(bEle).position().left) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("w") / 2) + "px";
                $(bEle).css({
                    transform: 'rotate(' + this.deg + 'deg)',
                    left: this.l,
                    top: this.t,
                    width: this.w,
                    height: this.h,
                    opacity: this.o
                });
            },
            complete: function () {
                //alert("sasa");
                //$(bEle).css({ "opacity": 0 });
            }
        });
    });
    $(":animated").promise().done(function () {
        //code here
        $.each(boneEle, function (index, bEle) {
            //$(bEle).css({ "opacity": 1 });
            $({
                deg: 360, w: 0, h: 0,
                l: parseFloat($(bEle).position().left),
                t: parseFloat($(bEle).position().top),
                o: 0,
            }).animate({
                deg: 0,
                w: that.allPositions[index].w, h: that.allPositions[index].h,
                l: that.allPositions[index].x,
                t: that.allPositions[index].y,
                o: 1
            }, {
                duration: 1000,
                index: index,
                step: function () {
                    // in the step-callback (that is fired each step of the animation),
                    // you can use the `now` paramter which contains the current
                    // animation-position (`0` up to `angle`)
                    //let xx = parseFloat($(bEle).position().left) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("w") / 2) + "px";
                    $(bEle).css({
                        transform: 'rotate(' + this.deg + 'deg)',
                        width: this.w,
                        height: this.h,
                        left: this.l,
                        top: this.t,
                        opacity: this.o
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}}
```

JavaScript and CSS & JS Includes in the head of HTML:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
    h1 {
        font-size: 72px;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }

    .side-car {
        font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 40px;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .col {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .filter-active {
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-weight: bolder;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var theContactApp = {
        iso_demo: {},
        start_action: function () {
            theContactApp.iso_demo = new IsoMetric(".TheContainer", ".my-item", 3);
            theContactApp.doCarousel();
            $("#animationOption").change((e) => theContactApp.DecideAnimation(e));
        },
        doCarousel: function () {
            $('.carousel').carousel({
                interval: 100,
                wrap: true,
                pause: 'hover'
            });
        },
        DecideAnimation: function (e) {
            theContactApp.iso_demo.SetAnimation(parseInt($(e.target).val()));
        },
    }; $(document).ready(() => theContactApp.start_action());
</script>
```

HTML in the body:

```
<section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" style="margin-bottom:-10px;">
                <h2 style="color:blue;">Click them and enjoy . . .</h2>
                <span class="text-primary rounded-circle m-2" style="cursor:pointer;font-size:44px;" onclick="theContactApp.iso_demo.TheClick(event, '.my-all')">&#10057;</span>
                <span class="text-primary rounded-circle m-2 " style="cursor:pointer;font-size:44px;" onclick="theContactApp.iso_demo.TheClick(event, '.1')">&#10112;</span>
                <span class="text-primary rounded-circle m-2 " style="cursor:pointer;font-size:44px;" onclick="theContactApp.iso_demo.TheClick(event, '.2')">&#10113;</span>
                <span class="text-primary rounded-circle m-2 " style="cursor:pointer;font-size:44px;" onclick="theContactApp.iso_demo.TheClick(event, '.3')">&#10114;</span>
                <div class="m-2" style="float:right;">
                    <select class="form-select"  id="animationOption" style="display:inline; color:darkgray;margin-top:-10px;">
                        <option value="1">ZoomOut Move In And ZoomIn</option>
                        <option value="2">FadeOff Appear And FadeIn</option>
                        <option value="3" selected>Implode AND Explode</option>
                        <option value="4">Rotation</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="container TheContainer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="display-6 overflow-hidden my-item 1 my-all">
                        <img style="display: block ; height:200px;" src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/FlexStart/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg" />
                        <span class="badge bg-dark rounded-pill" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:120px;opacity:.5;" >1</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="display-6 overflow-hidden my-item 2 my-all">
                        <img style="display: block; height:200px;" src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/FlexStart/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-2.jpg" />
                        <span class="badge bg-dark rounded-pill" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:120px;opacity:.5;">2</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="display-6 overflow-hidden my-item 3 my-all">
                        <img style="display: block;height:200px;" src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/FlexStart/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-3.jpg" />
                        <span class="badge bg-dark rounded-pill" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:120px;opacity:.5;">3</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="display-6 overflow-hidden my-item 1 my-all">
                        <img style="display: block;height:200px;" src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/FlexStart/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-4.jpg" />
                        <span class="badge bg-dark rounded-pill" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:120px;opacity:.5;">11</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="display-6 overflow-hidden my-item 2 my-all">
                        <img style="display: block;height:200px;" src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/FlexStart/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-5.jpg" />
                        <span class="badge bg-dark rounded-pill" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:120px;opacity:.5;">22</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="display-6 overflow-hidden my-item 3 my-all">
                        <img style="display: block;height:200px;" src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/FlexStart/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-6.jpg" />
                        <span class="badge bg-dark rounded-pill" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:120px;opacity:.5;">33</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="display-6 overflow-hidden my-item 1 my-all">
                        <img style="display: block;height:200px;" src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/FlexStart/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-7.jpg" />
                        <span class="badge bg-dark rounded-pill" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:120px;opacity:.5;">111</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="display-6 overflow-hidden my-item 2 my-all">
                        <img style="display: block;height:200px;" src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/FlexStart/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-8.jpg" />
                        <span class="badge bg-dark rounded-pill" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:120px;opacity:.5;">222</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="display-6 overflow-hidden my-item 3 my-all">
                        <img style="display: block;height:200px;" src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/FlexStart/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-9.jpg" />
                        <span class="badge bg-dark rounded-pill" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:120px;opacity:.5;">333</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="display-6 overflow-hidden my-item 1 my-all">
                        <img style="display: block;height:200px;" src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/FlexStart/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg" />
                        <span class="badge bg-dark rounded-pill" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:120px;opacity:.5;">1111</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="display-6 overflow-hidden my-item 2 my-all">
                        <img style="display: block;height:200px;" src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/FlexStart/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-2.jpg" />
                        <span class="badge bg-dark rounded-pill" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:120px;opacity:.5;">2222</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="display-6 overflow-hidden my-item 3 my-all">
                        <img style="display: block;height:200px;" src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/FlexStart/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-3.jpg" />
                        <span class="badge bg-dark rounded-pill" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:120px;opacity:.5;">3333</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

That is all folks, no external CSS needed, I have provided 4 effects, one can make more easily

Answer (score 0):

I am being limited by the number of characters, I have an update of the IsoMetric class

```
class IsoMetric {
    // 1: ZoomOutMoveInAndZoomIn, 2: FadeOffAppearAndFadeIn, 3: ImplodeExplode, 4: Rotation, 5: JustMove, 6: ExpandFadeMoveInAndZoomBack, 7: ScaleInScaleOut
    // 8: RotationY
    constructor(item_container, item_identifier, animationOption) {
        this.animationOption = animationOption ? animationOption : 1;
        this.jItemsContainer = $(item_container);
        this.leftCont = this.jItemsContainer.position().left;
        this.topCont = this.jItemsContainer.position().top;
        this.wdCont = parseFloat(this.jItemsContainer.width());
        this.htCont = parseFloat(this.jItemsContainer.height());
        this.eleJArray = $(item_identifier);
        this.eleArray = this.eleJArray.toArray();
        this.allPositions = [];
        let that = this;
        $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, ele) {
            let $ele = $(ele);
            let pos = $ele.position();
            let onePos = {
                "x": parseFloat(pos.left.toFixed(2)) + "px", "y": parseFloat(pos.top.toFixed(2)) + "px",
                "w": parseFloat($ele.width().toFixed(2)), "h": parseFloat($ele.height().toFixed(2)),
                "scale": 1
            };
            that.allPositions.push(onePos);
            $ele.attr(onePos);
            let par = $ele;
            //while (true) { //I restore width of all parents leading up to the container.
            //    par = $(par).parent();
            //    if (par[0] === that.jItemsContainer[0]) break;
            //    $(par).css({ "width": $(par).width(), "height": $(par).height() });
            //}
        });
        $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, ele) {
            let $ele = $(ele);
            $ele.css({ "position": "absolute", "left": $ele.attr("x"), "top": $ele.attr("y"), "transform": "rotate(0deg) scale(1)" });
        });
        this.jItemsContainer.css({ "width": this.wdCont + "px", "height": this.htCont + "px" });
    }
    Filter(e, selector) {
        switch (this.animationOption) {
            case 1:
                this.ZoomOutMoveInAndZoomIn(e, selector);
                break;
            case 2:
                this.FadeOffAppearAndFadeIn(e, selector);
                break;
            case 3:
                this.ImplodeExplode(e, selector);
                break;
            case 4:
                this.Rotation(e, selector);
                break;
            case 5:
                this.JustMove(e, selector);
                break;
            case 6:
                this.ExpandFadeMoveInAndZoomBack(e, selector);
                break;
            case 7:
                this.ScaleInScaleOut(e, selector);
                break;
            case 8:
                this.RotationY(e, selector);
                break;
        }
    }
    SetAnimation(option) {
        this.animationOption = option;
        let that = this;
        $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, ele) {
            let $ele = $(ele);
            $ele.css({
                transform: "rotate(0deg) scale(1)", opacity: 1,
                left: that.allPositions[index].x, top: that.allPositions[index].y,
                width: that.allPositions[index].w, height: that.allPositions[index].h,
            });
        });
    }
    ZoomOutMoveInAndZoomIn(e, selector) {
        let boneEle = $(selector);
        let that = this;
        $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, bEle) {
            $(bEle).animate({
                "width": 0,
                "height": 0,
                "left": parseFloat($(bEle).position().left) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("w") / 2),
                "top": parseFloat($(bEle).position().top) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("h") / 2),
                //"opacity": 0,
            }, 200, function () {
                //$(bEle).css({ "opacity": 0 });
                //$(bEle).css({ "display": "none" });
            });
        });
        $.each(boneEle, function (index, bEle) {
            //$(bEle).css({ "display": "block" });
            $(bEle).animate({
                "left": that.allPositions[index].x,
                "top": that.allPositions[index].y,
                "width": $(bEle).attr("w"),
                "height": $(bEle).attr("h"),
                //"opacity": 1
            }, 500);
        });
    }
    FadeOffAppearAndFadeIn(e, selector) {
        let boneEle = $(selector);
        let that = this;
        $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, bEle) {
            $(bEle).animate({ "opacity": 0, }, 2000, function () {
                $(bEle).css({ "width": 0, "height": 0 });
            });
        });
        $(":animated").promise().done(function () {
            //code here
            $.each(boneEle, function (index, bEle) {
                $(bEle).css({
                    "left": that.allPositions[index].x,
                    "top": that.allPositions[index].y,
                    "width": that.allPositions[index].w,
                    "height": that.allPositions[index].h
                });
                $(bEle).animate({
                    "opacity": 1
                }, 2000);
            });
        });
    }
    ImplodeExplode(e, selector) {
        let boneEle = $(selector);
        let that = this;
        let Cx = that.leftCont + (that.wdCont / 2); let Cy = that.topCont + (that.htCont / 2);
        $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, bEle) {
            $(bEle).animate({
                "left": Cx, //that.allPositions[index].x,
                "top": Cy, //that.allPositions[index].y,
                "width": 0,
                "height": 0,
            }, 100);
        });
        $(":animated").promise().done(function () {
            //code here
            $.each(boneEle, function (index, bEle) {
                $(bEle).animate({
                    "left": that.allPositions[index].x,
                    "top": that.allPositions[index].y,
                    "width": $(bEle).attr("w"),
                    "height": $(bEle).attr("h"),
                    "opacity": 1
                }, 400);
            });
        });
    }
    Rotation(e, selector) {
        let boneEle = $(selector);
        let that = this; let count = 0; let sAngle = 0; let endEngle = 360 * 5;
        $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, bEle) {
            $({
                deg: sAngle, w: $(bEle).width(), h: $(bEle).height(),
                l: parseFloat($(bEle).position().left),
                t: parseFloat($(bEle).position().top),
                o: 1
            }).animate({
                deg: endEngle, w: 0, h: 0,
                l: parseFloat($(bEle).position().left) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("w") / 2),
                t: parseFloat($(bEle).position().top) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("h") / 2),
                o: 0
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                index: index,
                step: function () {
                    // in the step-callback (that is fired each step of the animation),
                    // you can use the `now` paramter which contains the current
                    // animation-position (`0` up to `angle`)
                    //let xx = parseFloat($(bEle).position().left) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("w") / 2) + "px";
                    $(bEle).css({
                        transform: 'rotate(' + this.deg + 'deg)',
                        left: this.l,
                        top: this.t,
                        width: this.w,
                        height: this.h,
                        opacity: this.o
                    });
                },
                complete: function () {
                    //alert("sasa");
                    //$(bEle).css({ "opacity": 0 });
                    ++count;
                }
            });
        });

        function TheTheFinalAct() {
            $.each(boneEle, function (index, bEle) {
                //$(bEle).css({ "opacity": 1 });
                $({
                    deg: endEngle, w: 0, h: 0,
                    l: parseFloat($(bEle).position().left),
                    t: parseFloat($(bEle).position().top),
                    o: 0,
                }).animate({
                    deg: sAngle,
                    w: that.allPositions[index].w, h: that.allPositions[index].h,
                    l: that.allPositions[index].x,
                    t: that.allPositions[index].y,
                    o: 1
                }, {
                    duration: 1000,
                    index: index,
                    step: function () {
                        // in the step-callback (that is fired each step of the animation),
                        // you can use the `now` paramter which contains the current
                        // animation-position (`0` up to `angle`)
                        //let xx = parseFloat($(bEle).position().left) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("w") / 2) + "px";
                        $(bEle).css({
                            transform: 'rotate(' + this.deg + 'deg)',
                            width: this.w,
                            height: this.h,
                            left: this.l,
                            top: this.t,
                            opacity: this.o
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        //$(this.eleJArray).promise().done(function () {
        //    TheTheFinalAct();
        //});
        function WaitForAllAnimationsToBeOver() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (count >= that.eleArray.length) TheTheFinalAct();
                else WaitForAllAnimationsToBeOver();
            }, 500);
        }
        WaitForAllAnimationsToBeOver();
    }
    RotationY(e, selector) {
        let boneEle = $(selector);
        let that = this; let count = 0; let startAngle = 0; let endAngle = 360 * 5;
        $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, bEle) {
            $({
                deg: startAngle, w: $(bEle).width(), h: $(bEle).height(),
                l: parseFloat($(bEle).position().left),
                t: parseFloat($(bEle).position().top),
                o: 1
            }).animate({
                deg: endAngle, w: 0, h: 0,
                l: parseFloat($(bEle).position().left) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("w") / 2),
                t: parseFloat($(bEle).position().top) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("h") / 2),
                o: 0
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                index: index,
                step: function () {
                    // in the step-callback (that is fired each step of the animation),
                    // you can use the `now` paramter which contains the current
                    // animation-position (`0` up to `angle`)
                    //let xx = parseFloat($(bEle).position().left) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("w") / 2) + "px";
                    $(bEle).css({
                        transform: 'rotateY(' + this.deg + 'deg)',
                        //left: this.l,
                        //top: this.t,
                        //width: this.w,
                        //height: this.h,
                        opacity: this.o
                    });
                },
                complete: function () {
                    ++count;
                }
            });
        });

        function TheTheFinalAct() {
            $.each(boneEle, function (index, bEle) {
                $({
                    deg: endAngle, w: 0, h: 0,
                    l: parseFloat($(bEle).position().left),
                    t: parseFloat($(bEle).position().top),
                    o: 0,
                }).animate({
                    deg: startAngle,
                    w: that.allPositions[index].w, h: that.allPositions[index].h,
                    l: that.allPositions[index].x,
                    t: that.allPositions[index].y,
                    o: 1
                }, {
                    duration: 1000,
                    index: index,
                    step: function () {
                        // in the step-callback (that is fired each step of the animation),
                        // you can use the `now` paramter which contains the current
                        // animation-position (`0` up to `angle`)
                        //let xx = parseFloat($(bEle).position().left) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("w") / 2) + "px";
                        $(bEle).css({
                            transform: 'rotateY(' + this.deg + 'deg)',
                            //width: this.w,
                            //height: this.h,
                            left: this.l,
                            top: this.t,
                            opacity: this.o
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        function WaitForAllAnimationsToBeOver() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (count >= that.eleArray.length) TheTheFinalAct();
                else WaitForAllAnimationsToBeOver();
            }, 500);
        }
        WaitForAllAnimationsToBeOver();
    }
    JustMove(e, selector) {
        let boneEle = $(selector);
        let that = this;
        $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, bEle) {
            $(bEle).animate({
                "left": (that.leftCont + that.wdCont / 2) - that.allPositions[index].w / 2,
                "top": (that.topCont + that.htCont / 2) - that.allPositions[index].h / 2,
            }, 20, function () {
                $(bEle).css({ "opacity": 0 });
            });
        });
        $.each(boneEle, function (index, bEle) {
            $(bEle).animate({
                "left": that.allPositions[index].x,
                "top": that.allPositions[index].y,
                "opacity": 1
            }, 200);
        });
    }
    ExpandFadeMoveInAndZoomBack(e, selector) {
        let boneEle = $(selector);
        let that = this; let count = 0;
        $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, bEle) {
            $({ scale: 1, o: 1 }).animate({ scale: 10, o: 0 },
                {
                    duration: 1000,
                    index: index,
                    step: function () {
                        // in the step-callback (that is fired each step of the animation),
                        // you can use the `now` paramter which contains the current
                        // animation-position (`0` up to `angle`)
                        //let xx = parseFloat($(bEle).position().left) + parseFloat($(bEle).attr("w") / 2) + "px";
                        $(bEle).css({
                            transform: 'scale(' + this.scale + ')',
                            opacity: this.o
                        });
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        //alert("sasa");
                        ++count;
                        $(bEle).css({ "width": 0, "height": 0 });
                    }
                });
        });
        function TheTheFinalAct() {
            $.each(boneEle, function (index, bEle) {
                $({
                    scale: 10, w: 0, h: 0, o: 0,
                    l: parseFloat($(bEle).position().left), t: parseFloat($(bEle).position().top),
                }).animate({
                    scale: 1, w: that.allPositions[index].w, h: that.allPositions[index].h, o: 1,
                    l: that.allPositions[index].x, t: that.allPositions[index].y,
                }, {
                    duration: 1000,
                    index: index,
                    step: function () {
                        $(bEle).css({
                            transform: 'scale(' + this.scale + ')',
                            left: this.l,
                            top: this.t,
                            width: this.w,
                            height: this.h,
                            opacity: this.o
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        function WaitForAllAnimationsToBeOver() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (count >= that.eleArray.length) TheTheFinalAct();
                else WaitForAllAnimationsToBeOver();
            }, 500);
        }
        WaitForAllAnimationsToBeOver();
    }
    ScaleInScaleOut(e, selector) {
        let boneEle = $(selector);
        let that = this; let count = 0;
        $.each(this.eleJArray, function (index, bEle) {
            $({ scale: 1 }).animate({ scale: 0 },
                {
                    duration: 500,
                    index: index,
                    step: function () {
                        if (parseInt($(bEle).attr("scale")) !== 0) $(bEle).css({ transform: 'scale(' + this.scale + ')' });
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        ++count;
                        $(bEle).attr({ "scale": 0 });
                    }
                });
        });
        function TheTheFinalAct() {
            $.each(boneEle, function (index, bEle) {
                $(bEle).attr({ "scale": 1 })
                $({
                    scale: 0,
                    l: parseFloat($(bEle).position().left), t: parseFloat($(bEle).position().top),
                }).animate({
                    scale: 1,
                    l: that.allPositions[index].x, t: that.allPositions[index].y,
                }, {
                    duration: 1000,
                    index: index,
                    step: function () {
                        $(bEle).css({
                            transform: 'scale(' + this.scale + ')',
                            left: this.l,
                            top: this.t,
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        function WaitForAllAnimationsToBeOver() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (count >= that.eleArray.length) TheTheFinalAct();
                else WaitForAllAnimationsToBeOver();
            }, 500);
        }
        WaitForAllAnimationsToBeOver();
    }
    Sort(e, attrib, isAsc) {
        let that = this;
        //if (!this.eleArrAsc) {
        this.eleArrAsc =
        this.eleArray.sort(function (a, b) {
            let lhs = parseInt($(a).attr(attrib));
            let rhs = parseInt($(b).attr(attrib));
            return isAsc ? lhs - rhs : rhs - lhs;
        });
        $.each(this.eleArrAsc, function (index, bEle) {
            $(bEle).animate({
                "left": that.allPositions[index].x,
                "top": that.allPositions[index].y,
            }, 200);
        });
    }
}
```